# Laravel not good work on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have a code (who works on remote server), but he don't want work on my VM linux (ubuntu 16).

Issues are varied :

- CSS isn't read
- @import and @expand don't work
- Laravel routes don't work

Apache 2 **rewrite_module**  is ok (classical solve for Laravel routes issue)

PHP 7 is ok (phpinfo is good), Laravel is ok (access to database via Eloquent is good).

I precise that my html code is generate via php artisan with blade.

I suppose that I forgot a step in my configuration but I don't see what...

Edit :

- Change on Apache's config DocumentRoot from root of application to /public solve the CSS issue.
- a valid .htaccess is now ok, without change.

So, now, my major issue is to find why
https://www.xxxxx.vvv/api/v3/docs  works and https://localhost/api/v3/docs doesn't.
Given that https//www.xxxxx.vvv/ and http://localhost/ work in the same way.

versions : php 7.0.3
Laravel 5.0.4

(and I don't want update)

Comment: Might have some issue with .htaccess file. You default .htaccess file provided in laravel documentation.

Comment: Getting any errors? File permissions are ok? Does it work when using `php artisan serve`? Nothing in `storage/logs/laravel.log`? Document_root set to the `public` folder in your vhost settings?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I don't have any .htaccess file.

Comment: @kerbholz just 404 error html. file permission ok. For php artisan serve... when I go on http://localhost:8000/ I go on the prod site.

When I try to go on one route, I have "invalid request"

Nothing on laravel.log

Hum, document_root is set to root folder, not public. I can try this.

Comment: Take a look at the  [installation manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) to check if your forgot anything and also for an example of `.htaccess`

Comment: set documentRoot set to public solve first point. I have now active css.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `.htaccess` file missed. So put it in `public` directory with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I take the .htaccess file on server. But no change.